# Visual Studio 2015 .Net Core RC2 Tooling Preview 1

Tags: .net-framework, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Is there an offline version of the .net core tooling preview  for Visual Studio 2015 available?
I have a system that isnt connected to the internet and I need to install the tooling preview but cant find any offline installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution here:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/net-core-rc2-sdk-preview-1-offline-installer-ali-bahraminezhad

You can find the details about the solution in the link but basically you will need to download all the links below that are around 91 links and are ~500mb in size. 
After downloading all the files, Just put them in a folder called packages beside the "DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe" file. And you are good to go.

The links can be found at:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/al1b/MyOtherRepo/master/DotNetCore%20installer%20files.txt